# Sorting a collection in doctrine2

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-orm, doctrine, odm

I've written the following query (that may or may not be efficient, I'm still a newbie):

```
    $collection     = $this->dm->getConnection()->selectCollection('db_name', 'collection_name');
    $query          = array('array_name' => new \MongoId(id));
    $cursor         = $collection->find($query)->limit(9)->sort('r', 'desc');
```

I'm trying to sort by an r value that looks like this in the document:

```
"r": 0.58325652219355106354
```

but it isn't actually sorting it by that r-value. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure sort takes an array argument.  Try

```
->sort(['r' => 'desc]);
```

I looked it up... 
http://apigen.juzna.cz/doc/doctrine/mongodb/source-class-Doctrine.MongoDB.Cursor.html#564-585

Comment: Thanks, I need to start being more resourceful.